# High Scores logic in Unity using PlayerPrefsX

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a fairly basic 2d scrolling game in Unity, and one of the game modes is survival. When you die, this screen will load and allow you to input your high score, which will be saved into a high scores table once the button is pressed.

However, while I can replace the score it is higher than, I cannot for the life of me think of the logic that would instead put the score that was replaced into the position below it, then that score would drop by one, then the next score etc.

The stage I'm at is below, with the code that simply replaces all of the high scores lower than the current store deleted, because it isn't what needs to be done. I currently have five generic scores saved to the playerprefsX int array so i know all of the below code is working, its just the dropping all the scores down one and deleting the final score that is proving problematic for me

```
public class high_score_input : Game_Over {
private string name = "highscores";
private int score;
public int[] highscores = new int[5];


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    GameObject levelcontroller = GameObject.Find ("levelcontroller");
    survival_mode survival = levelcontroller.GetComponent<survival_mode> ();
    score = survival.setScore();
    highscores = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(name);}


void OnGUI()
{

    base.OnGUI ();
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width/10, 250, 120, 30), "Save High Score")) 
    {       


            for(int i = 0;i<highscores.Length;i++)
            {
                if(score>highscores[i])
                {
                    }
                }


        PlayerPrefsX.SetIntArray(name, highscores);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's a small array and this isn't performance-critical code, I'd go for something that's simple and avoids errors:

- Make sure that your score array is sorted.
- Does the new score beat the score in the last slot? If so, replace it.
- Make sure that your score array is sorted.

Given helper functions such as [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array.Sort(v=vs.90).aspx), this should be pretty quick.

Comment: Would that not only check the score in the last slot then?

Comment: Yes, but that's why the sorts are there. You only need to check if the new score beats the *lowest* score. The first sort makes that operation easier. The second sort makes sure your scores stay in order.

Comment: ah yes i think i understand what you mean